# How to specify concrete classes in factory for deferred instantiation / how to defer constructor call

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I have a several server programs which have a bunch of common code, but differ in a few child class implementations.  I use the abstract factory-like pattern something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Factory *factory = new Program1Factory();
    ServerThread theServer(factory);       // inject the dependencies
    theServer.start();
}
```

Factory is a pure abstract class, composed of the various bits I need to obtain the methods which have to vary from program to program.  It looks roughly like this:

```
class Factory {
    public: virtual foo *getFooThing() = 0;
    public: virtual bar *getBarThing() = 0;
};
```

The concrete declaration and implementation for one program might look like this:

```
class Program1Factory : public Factory {
    public: virtual foo *getFooThing() { return new Program1Foo(); }
    public: virtual bar *getBarThing() { return new Program1Bar(); }
};
```

This worked fine until I got to a bunch of methods which themselves are child classes of a library over which I have no control.

In that library, the constructors of each of the classes require the data to be processed to be provided in the constructor!  But my program does not yet have the data; it's just starting up and declaring its factory.  Only once all the methods are set up and the threads start, do my server programs receive transactions which are the input to the constructors.

That is to say, in the example above, I cannot simply say:

```
return new Program1Bar()
```

because the class from which Program1Bar is derived only has a constructor that looks like

```
Program1Bar(string *inputString, string *outputString)
```

I don't have those values at the time my factory is instantiated.

I need to somehow create a pointer to the concrete class I want, store that pointer in my factory, and -- the hard part I cannot figure out -- instantiate (call the constructor) for those classes when data finally arrives.

How can I go about this?

Comment: It is not clear why you are trying to call `getFooThing` in the first place when you don't have data to build it from.

Comment: The data is not required to build it; the library is just written that way.

Comment: The input strings are formatted to the X12 standard.  Depending on destination, they need to be transformed slightly.  The library knows how to parse X12.  I am using it to create filters which do the transformation.  Each server must perform different transformations.  Hence, I am trying to build references to child classes with the differing transformations encapsulated within them while using the parent classes' understanding of X12.  A server will process many such strings, but will only use one filter.

Comment: Now it's even less clear. You have said you must wait until data becomes available, and only then instantiate your base class. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm sorry for lack of clarity.  The library is coded such that the base class constructors require input strings (and output string vars).  But the derived classes don't actually DO anything with those strings until I call their unique methods.  So the library is requiring me to have the data in hand to instantiate the object.  I just want to create pointers to the derived classes so that I can instantiate the correct version when I finally get the data the base classes require.  The pointer will be of the base class type, so that I don't have duplicated code all over the place.

Comment: Would it help if I stated the problem in more generic terms in the original question, instead of using my tiny fabricated example code?

Comment: "create pointers to the derived classes so that I can instantiate the correct version when I finally get the data" --- do you actually do something with these objects *before* the data arrives?

Comment: No.  I'm simply trying to have a way to construct the proper derived class in each server while using common "driver" code.  It's entirely possible I'm approaching the whole problem the wrong way.  :-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With those restrictions your `Program1Bar` class cannot be a subclass of the 3rd party library. Hard to talk abstract, but one suggestion would be for you to define a class like `Task1Bar` which is a subclass of your 3rd party library.

Then somewhere inside `ProgramBar1::someMethod` you can make your call to `new Task1Bar`. If you need the 3rd party library to persist across methods you can always define a member `Task1Bar* task1` inside your `Program1Bar` class.

Just a suggestion, As I said, hard to define in the abstract.

Comment: This sounds like it's close to a solution, if I understand correctly.  So I'd store my `Program1Bar` pointer in the factory object, just as I do for classes without the silly constructor problem.  But then in my generic code shared by all servers, I'd have to add a bit of code to do the little extra work of calling `Program1Bar::someMethod()` to initialize the member which would hold the result from the `new Task1Bar()` call.  Does that sound right?

Comment: I assume there is already `someMethod` in you `Program1Bar` class which is called by the generic server code. So somewhere in there is where you would make the `new` call. You may need to re-define a method (assuming it virtual) to set up your custom stuff, then call the base class. So ideally you wouldn't need to change generic server code.

Comment: That's correct, although all of the servers face the same situation, so changing the generic server code is harmless.  Let me give that a try and I'll get back to this question with an accepted answer, or more questions.